# Use one Spring Framework autowired Component in another Component

Tags: java, spring

How can I use one Spring Framework autowired `Component` in another `Component`?

Currently, I receive the following compilation failure:

```
Component2.java:[15,13] variable comp1 might not have been initialized
```

To reproduce:

Use Spring initializr to create a Spring project. (Java 20 / Spring 2.7.14 / Maven / JAR.)

Project structure:

```
$ tree src/main
src/main
├── java
│   └── com
│       └── example
│           └── demo
│               ├── Component1.java
│               ├── Component2.java
│               └── DemoApplication.java
└── resources
    └── application.yml
```

Contents:

```yaml
# src/main/resources/application.yml
foo: bar
```

```java
// src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.demo")
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```java
// src/main/java/com/example/demo/Component1.java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@Component
public class Component1 {

    private final String foo;

    public void initialize() {
        System.out.println("initialized");
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("doing stuff");
    }

    @Autowired
    public Component1(
        @Value("${foo}") String foo
    ) {
        this.foo = foo;
        System.out.println("set foo to " + foo);
    }
}
```

```java
// src/main/java/com/example/demo/Component2.java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@Component
public class Component2 {

    private final Component1 comp1;

    @Autowired
    public Component2(Component1 comp1) {
        this.comp1.initialize();
    }

    public void theMethod() {
        this.comp1.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Above, the purpose is for `Component1` to be auto-constructed from `application.yml` properties. But then: how do I use an instance of this class in another class?

```bash
$ mvn clean spring-boot:run
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/brsolomon/Downloads/demo/src/main/java/com/example/demo/Component2.java:[15,13] variable comp1 might not have been initialized
```

I realize that the exception raised is from calling `new Component1()` with no arguments, since it is expecting one. But my goal is to have it constructed automatically with arguments from `application.yml` without needing `new Component1()` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to autowire the required component.

```
@Component
public class Component2 {

    private final Component1 comp1;

    @Autowired
    public Component2(Component1 comp1) {
        this.comp1 = comp1;
    }

    public void theMethod() {
        this.comp1.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Spring will inject the `Component1` bean in `Component2` when creating it.

Looking at Component1, it seems like it needs additional initialization before usage. This can be achieved using by annotating init method with `@PostConstruct`, or by implementing [InitializingBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html).

Comment: Do you mind adding a `PostConstruct` example? With the added `@Autowired`, I still receive `Component2.java:[15,13] variable comp1 might not have been initialized`

Comment: @BradSolomon Can you edit question with your attempt? This seems like compilation error, [PostContruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) won't help with that, it's about additional initializations in component1.

Comment: Updated question description

Comment: @BradSolomon You call `this.comp1.initialize();`, but you have not assigned a value to it, you missed `this.comp1 = comp1;` from my example. If `Component1.initialize()` is one time initialization for component 1, you can use PostConstruct on method `initialize()` in order no to do it manually.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. That resolved it, build successful.